# Difference between the methods .pipe() and .subscribe() on a RXJS observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I recently notice that I can return a value inside `.pipe()` but not inside `.subscribe()`.

What is the difference between these two methods?

For example if I have this function, let's call it 'deposit', which is supposed to return the account balance, if I do this:

```
deposit(account, amount){
    return this.http.get('url')
    .subscribe(res => {
        return res;
    }
}
```

It returns an observable and if I do this:

```
deposit(account, amount){
    return this.http.get('url')
    .pipe(
        map(res => {
            return res;
        });
    );
}
```

It returns the account balance as expected.

So why?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The `pipe` method is for chaining observable operators, and the `subscribe` is for activating the observable and listening for emitted values.

The `pipe` method was added to allow *webpack* to drop unused operators from the final JavaScript bundle. It makes it easier to build smaller files.

> For example if I have this function, let's call it 'deposit', which supposed to return the account balance, if I do this:
>
> ```
> deposit(account, amount){
>     return this.http.get('url')
>     .subscribe(res => {
>         return res;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> It returns an observable

That isn't what it returns. It returns the `Subscription` object created when you called `Subscribe`.

> and if I do this:
>
> ```
> deposit(account, amount){
>     return this.http.get('url')
>     .pipe(
>         map(res => {
>             return res;
>         });
>     );
> }
> ```
>
> It returns the account balance as expected.

That isn't what it returns. It returns an `Observable` which uses a `map` operator. The map operator in your example does nothing.

Comment: This answer is now incomplete. It seems to be missing screenshots or code snippets

Comment: I think he's referring to the OP's code snippets, rather than duplicating them in the answer. This caught me out as well.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the OP's code snippets to improve readability, thx @ShafiqJetha for pointing what was missing.

Comment: I think this answer really needs an explanation on whether you can move a lambda in `.subscribe()` inside the `.pipe()`.

Answer (score 7):

## Examples

One important differece is  that when you not execute `subscribe`, request will newer be send and `pipe` will be never executed. Here are working examples which shows the difference

- Subscribe

  ```js
  const { interval, of } = rxjs;
  const { delay, take } = rxjs.operators;

  this.http = { get: (url)=> of(url).pipe(delay(1000), take(1)) } // request simulator

  deposit = (account, amount) => {
      return this.http.get('url')
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log('hello from subscriber');
            return res;
        })
  }

  let subscription = deposit('',''); // immediately send request
  // you can cancel request by subscription.unsubscribe()

  console.log('subscribed');
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  ```
- Pipe

  ```js
  const { interval, of,  } = rxjs;
  const { delay, take, map } = rxjs.operators;

  this.http = { get: (url)=> of(url).pipe(delay(1000), take(1)) } // request simulator

  deposit = (account, amount) => {
      return this.http.get('url')
          .pipe(
              map(res => {
                  console.log('hello from pipe');
                  return res;
              })
          );
  }

  const observable = deposit('',''); // this will return observable and do nothing


  console.log('nothing happen');
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  ```
- Pipe + Subscribe

  ```js
  const { interval, of,  } = rxjs;
  const { delay, take, map } = rxjs.operators;

  this.http = { get: (url)=> of(url).pipe(delay(1000), take(1)) } // request simulator

  deposit = (account, amount) => {
      return this.http.get('url')
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
                console.log('hello from pipe');
                return res;
            })
        );
  }

  const observable = deposit('',''); // this will return observable and do nothing

  const subscription = observable.subscribe(result => { // this will send request 
    console.log('hello from subscriber')
  }); 

  // subscription.unsubscribe() - this will cancel request
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  ```