# Unit testing asynchronous code including setInterval in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous

I am using Angular 7+.

**`Summary of the problem :`**

I have a code inside which there is a `setInterval` method which calls a url method of a service to retrieve data every `1000 milliseconds`. Also note that i do not want my program to first wait for 1000 ms and then call the url method, i.e why i have *pre called* the method ***only once*** before setInterval. Do let me know how to `test` this exact same behaviour. Also please do not bother much about the implementation as it is done according to **business requirement which i cannot disclose**.

**`Problem Statement:`**

Suppose i have a url to which i check every 1 second whether i am getting data or not. The call to this url is made inside a function `getDataFromUrl` , inside a `service` injected into the component.

Please refer the code below.

```
someStorage = {};

constructor(private service: someService){}
ngOnDestroy(){
   clearInterval(this.clearPeriodicRefresh);
}

ngOnChanges(){
    let context = this;
    this.periodicRefresh(context);
    this.clearPeriodicRefresh = setInterval(function(){
        this.periodicRefresh(context);
    },1000);
}

periodicRefresh(self){
    self.service.getDataFromUrl(url).subscribe(res => {
        someStorage[res] = true;
    },
    err =>{
       console.log(" Error Occured "); 
    });
}
```

Now i am unit testing the code like this:

```
it('should check for async data from url', fakeAsync()=>{
    someServiceStub.getDataFromUrl.and.returnValue(of("chandni chowk"));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.someStorage["chandni chowk"]).toBe(true); // executes successfully
    
    setInterval(()=>{
        someServiceStub.getDataFromUrl.and.returnValue(of("delhi"));    
    },1000);
    
    tick(1000); // in milliseconds
    discardPeriodicTasks();
    
    expect(component.someStorage["delhi"]).toBe(true);          // throws error
    
}));
```

The second expect statement shows :

```
ERROR : expected undefined to be true
```

I do not know the reason why . However, if i do a **`tick(2000)`** instead of **`tick(1000)`**, then it works. Again i am not sure why it gets skipped earlier.

**`NOTE`** : Any timer between 1000 and 2000 i.e for example till `tick(1900)` throws the same error, and anytime after 2000 milliseconds works fine.

**Also please tell me how to write better tests if there is any other way for this.**

Comment: Hi mate, setInterval on ngOnChanges is a bad idea with not clearing the interval, as it is always adding a new interval function. Also you could just use an arrow function on setInterval like this ```setInterval(() => { ... }``` and there shouldnt be any need for passing any context around, as "this" is component wide context in angular. BTW what are u trying to test here? Your storage? Your service? Your component? regards

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz with your setup.

Comment: Hello @sagat, please see the edited code.

Comment: clearInterval(this.clearPeriodicRefresh); this wont help on ngOndestroy, as ngOnChanges is called way more often during component lifetime, while onDestroy is only called when the component disappears.

Comment: easiest way to help you is provide a stackblitz please

Comment: Sorry man, it is actually related to business , i wrote up a mock code to display the same behaviour. I understand about the clear refresh thing, but can you help me with my problem of unit test? Also a better approach for that clear refresh thing too.. please suggest.

Comment: Okay, I have some suggestions for the component code. Use interval from rxjs for making repeating calls. Also why are u making an http request from ngOnChanges? Whats the trigger here? Make the http call on ngOnInit you dont need the context stuff there. Not necessary. Did u maybe forget to do a ```fixture.detectChanges()``` in here ```setInterval(()=>{
        someServiceStub.getDataFromUrl.and.returnValue(of("delhi"));
    },1000);```

Comment: Hey @sagat , please do not bother about the implementation as it done as per requirements. What you are saying maybe is right from your context, but in mine i need ngOnChanges , please help me with the test cases, and if you have some problem understanding the code i have written do let me know. Also see my summary of the problem i wanted.

Comment: @KL_KISNE_DEKHA_HAI  You cannot ignore Sagat's comments relating to ngOnChanges as this may be the root of your problem.

Comment: Also i am not ignoring anyone's comments it is just that i want it that way only.

Comment: @KL_KISNE_DEKHA_HAI  I did not downvote. I'm done.