# angular pipe vs subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

```js
const sites$: Observable<ISiteData<IRoleData>[]> = this.store.select('auth', 'user', 'sites');

sites$.pipe(
            tap((x) => console.log(x)),
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$$),
        );
sites$.subscribe((val: any) => console.log(val)).unsubscribe();
```

In this situation, the subscribe method is printing the entire object returned. The pipe is not printing anything. How / Why is this going wrong ?

**I need to be get the both of them to work the same way.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between the methods .pipe() and .subscribe() on a RXJS observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269372/difference-between-the-methods-pipe-and-subscribe-on-a-rxjs-observable)

Comment: I added some clarification to the question which the answer below addresses better than the original answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `pipe` creates new wrapped obserable that you should subscribe to.

What you should do is

```
observable.pipe(....).subscribe();
```